# How to correctly transform the following grammar to fall into LL(1)

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, left-recursion, ambiguous-grammar

Recently I'm trying to write a compiler for a modified subset of OCaml, through the official documentation I've written a similar grammar given below as what they do to the expressions:(since its a slightly modified version so there will be some differences)

```antlr
Statement ::= LetDef Statement | ε
LetDef ::= 'let' Definition.
Definition ::= 'rec' LetBinding | LetBinding
LetBinding ::= 'ident' '=' Expr
Constant ::= 'int_literal' | 'float_literal' | 'string_literal' | 'char_literal' | 'bool_literal' | 'unit_literal'
InfixOp ::= '&&' | '||' | '=' | '!=' | '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '+.' | '-.' | '*.' | '/.'
Expr ::= Constant 
    | '(' Expr ')' 
    | LetDef 'in' Expr 
    | 'fun' 'ident' '->' Expr 
    | 'if' Expr 'then' Expr 'else' Expr
    | Expr 'as' 'ident'
    | Expr ';' Expr
    | Expr InfixOp Expr
```

Apparently, this grammar is neither LL nor any kind of LR. It seems that the last three productions, `Expr 'as' 'ident'`, `Expr ';' Expr`, and `Expr InfixOp Expr` caused this problem, but I don't know how to correctly translate it into a LL(1) grammar(I believe it can be done at all because such structures are common to see in a wide variety of programming languages, including those have claimed themselves are using LL(1) grammar, e.g., Java), I've tried things like left factor elimination and left recursion elimination and resolve first/follow set conflict but the problem still happens, as a beginner at grammar design, I may know where the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. Suppose that, for now, the precedence of the operators doesn't matter, how could I translate it into a LL(1) grammar correctly?

Comment: You can only disambiguate that grammar by defining operator precedences. And if you want the grammar to be LL(1), it must be disambiguated; ambiguous grammars are not deterministically parseable. Since you want an LL(1) grammar, you'll need to code the precedences into the grammar, using cascading precedence style. That's a place to start, anyway.

Comment: Why do you want an LL(1) grammar, though? Ocaml has perfectly good LALR(1) parser generators.

Comment: Because I want to write the parser manually to train my skill, and since LR grammars are mostly table-driven, they are better off using a parser generator instead of constructing a parser manually. Thanks for your advice, I'll try to add precedence rules to the grammar.